# VBA: How to drag formulaS to the last used row?

Tags: vba, excel

Good day, please help me. 
The scenario is like this, I have 7 different formulas assigned to 7 different top rows after the header. What I want to achieved is to drag this formulas down to the last used rows simultaneously. I successfully wrote a code on doing this but it is a static code, I want to do it in a dynamical way because every month the amount of data is different so my static code is not reliable.

Here is the code that I have wrote:

'format border

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("BK1", "BQ22").Select
```

borderMeFn

```
                Dim strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(1 To 7) As Variant
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(1) = "=COUNTIF(LSR_WISOR_USERS_" & month & ".xlsx!$C:$C,J2)" 'WISOR_COUNT - counts the PON_VER in LSR_WISOR_USER file.
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(2) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J2,LSR_WISOR_USERS_" & month & ".xlsx!$C:$E,3,FALSE),"""")"
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(3) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,CPXLIST_" & month & ".xlsx!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"""")"
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(4) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2, DDVRFY_" & month & ".xlsx!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"""")"
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(5) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,HTG_" & month & ".xlsx!$A:$D,4,FALSE),"""")"
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(6) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,RPON_" & month & ".xlsx!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"""")"
                    strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS(7) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2,PROV_PLAN_" & month & ".xlsx!$A:$F,6,FALSE),"""")"
                'apply formulas to designated cells
                With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
                    .Range("BK2:BQ2").formula = strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS
                End With
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BK2:BQ22").FillDown
                    'Range("BK2:BQ" & LastRow).FillDown
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCell As Range

'apply formulas to designated cells
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("BK2:BQ2").Formula = strFormulas_OR1_ASR_DATA_DETAILS

    ' use Find function to get last row 
    Set LastCell = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LastCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Error!", vbCritical
    End If

    .Range("BK2:BQ" & LastRow).FillDown
End With
```

Comment: Hi Shai, Thank you for you help, I think it is working now, I just need to test my other records to validate if the code is really working, Thank you very much for help, =)

Comment: @JCBA you're welcome :) now comes your part where you mark as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will trun green)

Comment: Hi Shia just a follow up question, I'm gonna need to apply the Find function a lot of times in my program, is there a way that I can assign it to a function let say "Private Sub findLastRowFn()" so that I can just easily call it when I needed it.